# Best mysql table design when storing form info?

Tags: mysql

I am designing a site which has lots of forms. There are about 20 different forms and each form has got its own fields. Therefore i would like to know what the best mysql table design is for storing text elements for each form. Elements such as field labels, placeholder texts, valudation errors etc.

```
 My design now is that i have one table with the following columns:

 Id areaName label placeholdertext errormsg
```

For one of my forms i then load all rows which has areaName equal to "name", "age" and "gender" (getting three rows for three fields which i insert into the template form. But is this the best way to do this? I am considering having a multilanguage setup, naming areaName _en to support english language.

Comment: You might want to look to an EAV database model

Comment: Yes. So i would have a language_id and from that language id and a form_id fetch all information used in a form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important consideration would be how your data is organised and binds logically, i.e. what relationships are there. Next, it comes down to how big your collection is. If you're eg programming a facebook app where you want to store the user's city and you expect 10000s of users, it's not a good idea to store the location as a text field in the same table. You'd have a field 'location_id' and a separate table "location" and link the information via the id. That way, you store every city only once and then reference it.

My point being that your DB design depends on many factors: speed, size, ease-of-development, personal preferences.

Answer (score 0):

with this, there would not really be a generic "best" way to do it. personally, i use

```
forms: form_id,form_action,form_method
forms_inputs: form_id,input_name,input_def_val,input_order,input_required,input_type
```

this allows any form to be edited via a control panel at any time, and you could localise these by simply adding input_locale to the end of forms_inputs

Answer (score 0):

I would store the data according to it's logic. Like I would make a separate table to store personal users data (**UserId, FirstName, MidName, LastName, BirthDate, Gender, UserLanguage, Timestamp**). Other data should be stored in other tables and can be connected to the "**User**" table through **UserId** key. Notice that I did not save the "age", because it will become outdated in less than a year. Store date of birth (**BirthDate**) instead. For multilanguage setup just use UTF-8 and store language id (such us "eng" or "spa" etc.) in every row, so you'll always know what language it is. For example, the table for storing your form data will look like: **MyFormId, UserId, Label, PlaceholderText, ErrorMsg, LangId, Timestamp**.